# Warning for GPU in tensorflow pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I recently had a problem with Tensorflow installing but I solved it by creating a virtual environment in anaconda navigator. I get a warning saying

> 2020-10-17 13:44:04.120482: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
> 2020-10-17 13:44:04.120745: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

*The thing is that I have a GPU on my laptop(T2000). How do I fix this?*

Comment: What versions of TF and CUDA are you using?

Comment: I am using tensorflow 2.1.o and my CUDA is 10.2

Answer (score 0):

did you install tensorflow with pip? If you did uninstall it and install  tensorflow using conda. Conda automatically installs cudnn 7.6.5 and CUDA Toolkit 10.1.243 and tensorflow 2.1.0. If you want tensorflow 2.2 first install 2.1.0 as described. Then use pip to install 2.2 with pip install tensorflow ==2.2.0. 2.2 is compatible with the toolkit and cudnn versions installed with 2.1. Conda can only install tensorflow up to version 2.1.0. Install whatever other packages you need using either pip or conda.

Comment: I installed by creating my own environment. Then I installed tensorflow using conda on the environment. I then I used that as my interpreter in pycharm. I did use pip as well but it would not let me use tensorflow giving me this error, "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found."

Comment: did you install tensorflow with conda first, Then install tensorflow 2.2 with pip?